# How to do statistical analysis on very large CSV files (over 200GB)?

Tags: r, large-data

Does anyone know how to do statistical analysis on very (very) large CSV files? I'm currently building a dataset for my prof, and once joined together it'll be a CSV file with size >200GB, 92 million rows and 75 columns. I know R base functions and readr can't import such a large file (tried and failed on a 90GB CSV). Is there any way I can do stats stuff on such a large dataset? Ideally a solution using R would be good but I'm open to other options as well.

Comment: You may get better answers at [DS.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

I would start by looking into the [`data.table` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html). It allows for fast reads and can do many operations very fast, ([benchmarks](https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/)).

The problem with `data.table`, and `base` R, is that you typically load all the dataset into memory. Given that your file is 200GB, you will need at least that much memory. Quite frankly, unless the task you are solving really needs all the data in memory, then this could be a waste of resources. I would at least try to learn about the other options.

Other options, which are less memory exhaustive, is to use a database, (some SQL database, e.g. `sqlite3`). You can use the `dbplyr` package to query the database with `dplyr` commands. This will consume much less memory, and you can create indices to make certain queries faster. The database will still take quite a lot of disc space, and some queries will be slower, since it could require a lot of random access reads.

Another option is to split the original file into smaller files, e.g. if there is a timestamp, split them by year, so one file for 2001, one for 2002, 2003, etc. Then you will to write a bit of extra code to query the data, but you will at least be able to load and access the data in R.

You can also save the smaller batches with `base::save`, which saves the file into an R binary file, which can be faster to load in many cases.

The solution really depends on the problem that you want to solve. Also consider whether you really need all these 75 columns, maybe you can get away with fewer and that saves a lot of space.

If it really is the case, that you need all the data, e.g. if you are doing clustering or something like that. Then I would still start with a smaller subset of the data to develop and iterate on. If you start on all the data, then the development cycle will be very long, in case you want to change, tweak or test something different.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1.  There are many good ideas here.  To them I would add that (1) initially putting the data into fourth normal form often will achieve a natural split into smaller tables, thereby making the process more practicable, and (2) it costs relatively little to build a machine with, say, 256 GB RAM (or as much as 1024 GB) and even less to spin up such an instance in the cloud.  Combining (1) with your idea of splitting into smaller files, I have processed a CSV file of 350 GB in `R` on a machine with 64 GB RAM.  The initial work does take a few hours of programming and computation, though.

Comment: (+1) There are other options, such as SPARK or the `ff` package, but using a database to store data does have the advantage of being familiar to almost everyone. I'd note that you can create one from within R using RSQLite, & send queries in SQL (if you don't know `dplyr`). If tables do have to be big, however, creating indices can take an age (@whuber) - though many hours up front is still a fair price to pay for queries that run in seconds